# Stripe authorization redirect response for preflight is invalid or requires "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" Header(redirect)

Tags: redirect, cors, webpack-dev-server, stripe-connect

Trying to follow the [Stripe Connect Rocket Rides Github Repo](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-connect-rocketrides) I am unable to do a redirect from my https webpack-dev-server using fetch. As you can see I am making a get request.

```
    return fetch(`https://localhost:3443/stripeAuthorize`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://localhost:3443",
        'Accept': '*/*',
      }
    })
    .then((data) => {
      return data.json()
    })
    .then((json) => {
      console.log('redirectjson', json)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('stripe redirect err caught: ', err)
    })
```

Looking inside the network tab of chrome I see status code '303 See Other' on both OPTIONS and GET

Request Headers:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6,th;q=0.4,zh-TW;q=0.2,zh;q=0.2,la;q=0.2,ja;q=0.2
Access-Control-Request-Headers:access-control-allow-origin
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Cache-Control:no-cache
```

I do notice that the GET network call is above the OPTIONS which is passed in by the browser, it seems odd the GET call would precede OPTIONS. I can't seem to get any other information from stripe or the http protocol. No error calling on the server

How can I debug this issue and why is the stripe redirect not working?

EDIT: I thought I made it clear that if I remove "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" I get the err:

> Failed to load
>   https://connect.stripe.com/express/oauth/authorize?client_id=ca_BR4uV37xvFoKjLE5g9g2wzcmYNT0jnXZ&state=xy5z4k7lpe7rkwyerlxv9rudi&stripe_user%5Bbusiness_type%5D=company:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://localhost:3443' is therefore not allowed
>   access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: Remove `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "localhost:3443";` from the request headers. That’s what’s causing your browser to send an OPTIONS request. The Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is strictly a *response* header for servers to send back. The only effect that adding it to a request will have is to cause browsers to do a preflight and so to cause something to break that would otherwise be working. Why are sending the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the request? To try to prevent some other error?

Comment: @sideshowbarker I appologize for not making myself more clear I thought I did, that if I remove the Access-Control-Allow-Origin I am not allowed access.

Comment: You’re also not allowed access if you put Access-Control-Allow-Origin into the request — instead that’s just causing you to get a different error due to triggering a preflight. It’s not enabling any new access. The problem’s that the response from `https://localhost:3443/stripeAuthorize` doesn’t have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. And because it doesn’t, your browser enforces the normal default same-origin Web security policy and blocks your frontend JavaScript code from having any access to the response. The fix is to configure that server to send back Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: That sounds logical and, running express, I though I could attach the header like:

res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://localhost:3443");

before my

  res.redirect(stripeConfig.authorizeURI + '?' + querystring.stringify(parameters))


however when I do this there is no change, I recieve error. When you say "the fix is to configure that server to send back Access-Control-Allow-Origin" do you mean to do something different?

Comment: The error cited in the question says `Failed to load https://connect.stripe.com/express/oauth/authorize…` so actually in order to fix that error, the `https://connect.stripe.com` server is the one you’d need to have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header sent back from. But since you don’t control that server, you’re not gonna be able to do that. So it’s looking like your only option is gonna end up being to make the request from your backend code instead — because it seems the request flow you’re trying to use is not one that’s mean to work from frontend JS code running in a browser.

Answer (score 2):

You've got some things a bit mixed up.

The `/authorize` endpoint in Rocket Rides is not meant to be requested with `fetch()` or AJAX, you're meant to navigate the browser to it.

What you're seeing is this: your server--the `/stripeAuthorize` endpoint--is redirecting to the Express onboarding flow (a HTML page that your user will onboard with). That's not configured with CORS, but you're downloading it with `fetch()`, so it fails.

Instead of `fetch('/stripeAuthorize').then(/*...*/)`, simply write this:

```
window.location.href = '/stripeAuthorize';
```

Your browser should be redirected and you'll find yourself (assuming everything is configured correctly) in the onboarding flow.

Comment: I know it's been a while since your answer, but does that mean you'd have to use a Cookie if you wanted to pass the user's Bearer Token along to the server? The server may want to decode the token and pre-populate Stripe form-fields based on the ID of the user in the DB, for example. Thanks.

Comment: @JamieCorkhill I'm not sure what you mean. You'll likely want to keep a session active on your website so that you know who the user is when they return from Express's OAuth flow (and sessions use cookies). Otherwise, there shouldn't be any bearer tokens on the client side (i.e., in the browser) that interact with Stripe directly. Please open a new question with more details if you need help!

Comment: @mattbasta I have a similar problem and a little confused with your answer above. Your answer seems to suggest that the call to '/stripeAuthorize' is taking place from the client.. I read the Rocket Rides  example as if the call is coming from the server (nodejs in my case). how would you suggest the call is made from the server?

Comment: @MichaelE There is no endpoint on Stripe's servers called `/stripeAuthorize`, so it would be defined by your application, not Stripe. For your application server to make a request to itself would be very unnecessary. Please start a new question with more details if you'd like me to dig into what you're seeing! I'm happy to have a look.

Comment: @mattbasta Thanks for the comments. I am aware there's no such end point. I was using the nomenclature used in the other comments. My comment was about using the res.redirect from nodejs. apparently it's flaky so I switched to res.json(stripeURLAuthorize) and handle the redirect to stripe in the client with location.href......with res.redirect apparently the browser handles the redirecting...not transparent enough for me.